# call mainActivity method from angularJs for paytm SDK

Tags: java, android, angularjs, ionic-framework, paytm

I want to implement Paytm payment gateway, I have a payWithPaytm button. On paytm documentation there is [this method](http://paywithpaytm.com/developer/paytm_sdk_doc?target=example) which has to be executed. On click of button, how to call this method from AngularJs. I am using ionic1.

I can think of one option i.e. to override

> shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)

above method. Is there any other way I can achieve this, I am newbie in android development.

I found answers on google like [this](http://simplifiedandroidcoding.blogspot.in/2016/09/how-to-integrate-paytm-wallet-in-android.html) but they are using layout file to create the buttons and attaching on click method on this but I have html and angularJs.

Comment: I think that paytm sdk should be converted into cordova plugin then you can call methods which are declared inside.

Comment: thanks for your reply, is there any other option, we can do this ? @PareshGami

Comment: Might be if paytm provider web option instead of sdk then you can otherwise plugin is only way

Comment: okay thanks... I'll see what i can do @PareshGami